# Library session do Codeigniter 3.0

Tags: codeigniter, session

Fiz uma função para realizar logoff no sistema, no entanto, quando utilizo a função `sess_destroy()` para destruir a sessão, o mesmo não permite exibir o `set_flashdata()`. Quando retiro a função `sess_destroy()` o `set_flashdata()` funciona normalmente. Alguém pode me dar uma dica do que pode ser?

Controller:

```
public function logoff(){
    $this->session->unset_userdata(array('user_id' => '', 'user_nome' => '', 'user_admin' => '', 'user_logado' => ''));
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    set_msg('logoffok', 'Logoff efetuado com sucesso!', 'sucesso');
    redirect('funcionario/login');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o CI 3, você apenas precisa informar as chaves do array para dar o unset das variaveis: no seu caso:

`$this->session->unset_userdata(array('user_id', 'user_nome', 'user_admin', 'user_logado'));`

Se você destruir a sessão, o flashdata não funcionará na página seguinte. Destrua sua sessão no seu método de login ou mantenha a sessão sem dados;

Segue um exemplo que estou usando:

```
    //construtor
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logado') && !in_array(uri_string(), array('admin/login', 'admin/autenticacao_json')))
            redirect(base_url('admin/login'));
    }

    //método de logoff
    public function logoff(){

        $this->session->unset_userdata(array('logado', 'id', 'nome', 'email'));

        $this->session->set_flashdata('aviso', '<div class="alert alert-info">Deslogado do sistema</div>');

        redirect(base_url('admin/login'));
    }

    //método de login
    public function login() {       
        if($this->session->userdata('logado')){            
            redirect(base_url('admin'));
        }

        //$this->session->sess_destroy();

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('admin/login');
    }
```

Comment: Coloquei no meu método login e funcionou perfeitamente, Tanks ;)